# jQuery Selector with :not Doesn't Work in IE7

Tags: jquery

Can someone tell me why this doesn't work in IE7 please and how to to best refactor it to work in IE7 as well as the other major browser such as Chrome, Firefox and Safari?

```
    var validTabSet = $('[tabindex]:not([tabindex=-1]):not([type=hidden]):not([disabled=true])');
```

Thanks

David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can factorize the selectors you pass to `:not` into a [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/):

```
var validTabSet = $("[tabindex]:not([tabindex=-1], [type=hidden], [disabled=true])");
```

If it still fails on IE7, you can use the [not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) method instead of a selector:

```
var validTabSet = $("[tabindex]").not("[tabindex=-1], [type=hidden], [disabled=true]");
```

Comment: Thanks - I get the same result as before with both methods.

Comment: This might be an issue with the `disabled` attribute, then. Try `[disabled=disabled]` instead of `[disabled=true]`.

Comment: sorry, still the same result.

Comment: var validTabSet = $(':input').filter(function (index) {
    return $(this).attr("tabindex") != -1 &&
           $(this).attr("type") != "hidden" &&
           $(this).attr("disabled") != "disabled"
})

Comment: @Federic, thanks for your help.  It's a pity as I liked your solutions